# Loop condition and #define

Tags: c, gcc

I have an bin data table, for sample purposes:

```
static const unsigned char test_bin[28800] = {0};

#define TEST_DATA_COLUMNS 2
#define TEST_DATA_ROWS (sizeof(test_bin)/sizeof(float)/TEST_DATA_COLUMNS);    
static const float (* test_data)[TEST_DATA_COLUMNS] = (const float (*)[TEST_DATA_COLUMNS]) test_bin;
```

This fails with `error: expected expression before ';' token`:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < TEST_DATA_ROWS ; i++);
```

But this works

```
size_t nrows = TEST_DATA_ROWS;
for(size_t i = 0; i < nrows ; i++);
```

Why?

[godbot for quick testing](https://godbolt.org/z/nb3zx7dqv)

Comment: You shouldn't put a `;` after `#define`

Comment: You define two macros, you terminate one with a `;` but not the other. Should macros be terminated?

Comment: Because of the `;` at the end of the TEST_DATA_ROWS definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the trailing semi-colon at the end of the define for `TEST_DATA_ROWS`

```
#define TEST_DATA_ROWS (sizeof(test_bin)/sizeof(float)/TEST_DATA_COLUMNS);
                                                                         ^
```

This means that the preprocessor generates the following for your loop

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof(test_bin)/sizeof(float)/TEST_DATA_COLUMNS); ; i++)
                                                                        ^ ^
```

Removing the `;` from the end of the define would fix things.

Comment: bummer, now I remember why I hated preprocess macros. BTW the size difference is considered by the division by sizeof(float)